# How do I add a linked document to a linked list using the Java API for OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I have an `OType.LINKLIST` field `children` in a class.

I can use the following command to update it:

```
update <parent_rid> add children = <child_rid>
```

But I don't know how to do this without using SQL, which is my goal.

#### code

```
ODocument doc=new ODocument("ClassA");
ODocument parentDoc=db.load(new ORecordId(rid));
```

How do I add `doc` to `parentDoc`'s field `children` without using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create class Doc
create class ParentDoc 
create property ParentDoc.children LINKLIST


insert into Doc set name = 'doc1'                               #12:0
insert into Doc set name = 'doc2'                               #12:1
insert into ParentDoc set name = 'pd', children = [#12:0]       #13:0
update #13:0 add children = #12:1
```

For what I understood you want a piece of code that replaces the last four commands using Java Document API.

```
try (ODatabaseDocument db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/DB")) {
    db.open("admin", "admin");

    ODocument doc1 = new ODocument("Doc");
    doc1.field("name", "doc1");
    doc1.save();

    List<OIdentifiable> linklist = new ArrayList();
    linklist.add(doc1);

    ODocument parent = new ODocument("ParentDoc");
    parent.field("children", linklist, OType.LINKLIST);
    parent.save();

    // ...

    ODocument doc2 = new ODocument("Doc");
    doc2.field("name", "doc2");
    doc2.save();

    List children = parent.field("children");
    children.add(doc2);
    parent.field("children", children);
    parent.save();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. is fetching the document with db.load that also fetches the link list adding it and then saving it again much slower than just doing the sql update command you think?

Comment: Don't know. I'll do some testing on this this afternoon and give you the feedback.

Comment: you rock. I suspected it would be like that , I think most of the things are faster with the customized Orient SQL. You also gave me good code because the pooltx was deprecated.

Comment: why you do update #13:0 add children=#12:1    and not children=[#12:0,#12:1] while inserting

Comment: You can do that. It's just an example how you can add more elements later.